# Acces to spider variable in pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this on my scrapy spider

```
def __init__(self, table=''):
    super(MgdealBotCrawlerSpider, self).__init__()
    self.table_name = table
```

I used this to start the spider from command line

```
scrapy crawl mgdeal_bot_crawler -a table=lego
```

I would like to use this arg to create a new table when the item is process here. how i can do it in pipeline.py

```
  def process_item(self, item, spider):

    # run db query in the thread pool
    d = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._do_upsert, item, spider)
    d.addErrback(self._handle_error, item, spider)
    # at the end return the item in case of success or failure
    d.addBoth(lambda _: item)
    # return the deferred instead the item. This makes the engine to
    # process next item (according to CONCURRENT_ITEMS setting) after this
    # operation (deferred) has finished.
    return d

def _do_upsert(self, conn, item, spider):
    """Perform an insert or update."""

    guid = self._get_guid(item)
    now = datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat(' ')

    conn.execute("""SELECT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM"""+table_name+"""WHERE guid = %s
    )""", (guid, ))
    ret = conn.fetchone()[0]
```

It seems i can't access to it . How can i managed to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to access the attribute using the spider instance `spider.table_name`:

```
def _do_upsert(self, conn, item, spider):
    """Perform an insert or update."""

    guid = self._get_guid(item)
    now = datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat(' ')

    conn.execute("""SELECT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM"""+spider.table_name+"""WHERE guid = %s
    )""", (guid, ))
    ret = conn.fetchone()[0]
```